# How to make a List of CheckBoxes like in the Alarm & Clock App

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

[image]
[image]

How can i make such alist of checkboxes, that they are left aligned to the button, from where it opens, and provide a opening and closing Animation, like in the Alarm & Clock App in Windows 10? I tried with Popups and Flyouts, but there isnt the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that this Control in the Alarm & Clock App is actually expanded from a `ComboBox` control.

So we can use a `ComboBox` to do this, for example:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{x:Bind comboitems}"
          PlaceholderText="{x:Bind contenttext, Mode=OneWay}" DropDownClosed="comboBox_DropDownClosed" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding dayofweek}" IsChecked="{Binding ischecked, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

To show the selected days on the `ComboBox` is a little complex, we can do this work in the code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<comboItem> comboitems = new ObservableCollection<comboItem>();

    private string _contenttext;

    public string contenttext
    {
        get
        {
            return _contenttext;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _contenttext)
            {
                _contenttext = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private int daycount;

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        showdays();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        comboitems.Clear();
        comboitems.Add(new comboItem { dayofweek = "Sunday", ischecked = false });
        comboitems.Add(new comboItem { dayofweek = "Monday", ischecked = true });
        comboitems.Add(new comboItem { dayofweek = "Tuesday", ischecked = true });
        comboitems.Add(new comboItem { dayofweek = "Wednesday", ischecked = true });
        comboitems.Add(new comboItem { dayofweek = "Thursday", ischecked = true });
        comboitems.Add(new comboItem { dayofweek = "Friday", ischecked = true });
        comboitems.Add(new comboItem { dayofweek = "Saturday", ischecked = false });
    }

    private void comboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, object e)
    {
        showdays();
    }

    private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    private void showdays()
    {
        contenttext = null;
        daycount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < comboBox.Items.Count(); i++)
        {
            comboItem item = comboBox.Items.ElementAt(i) as comboItem;
            if (item.ischecked)
            {
                contenttext = contenttext + item.dayofweek.Substring(0, 3) + ", ";
                daycount++;
            }
        }

        if (daycount != 0)
        {
            if (daycount == 2 && contenttext == "Sun, Sat, ")
            {
                contenttext = "Weekends";
            }
            else if (daycount == 5 && contenttext == "Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, ")
            {
                contenttext = "Weekdays";
            }
            else if (daycount == 7)
            {
                contenttext = "Every day";
            }
            else
            {
                contenttext = contenttext.TrimEnd(' ', ',');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            contenttext = "Only once";
        }
    }

}
```

And the `comboItem` class by my side is like this:

```
public class comboItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string dayofweek { get; set; }

    private bool _ischecked;

    public bool ischecked
    {
        get
        {
            return _ischecked;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _ischecked)
            {
                _ischecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you can find another easier way to convert days to specific string, eventually my method works here.

**Update**:

Here is the whole modified template style of the `ComboBox`, you can also edit the template by your self.

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,5,0,7" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxThemeMinWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltMediumLowBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <CarouselPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundAltMediumBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightBlue" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListMediumBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" />
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" />
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DropDownStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <SplitOpenThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <SplitCloseThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" FontWeight="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeFontWeight}" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeMargin}" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" />
                    <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <Border x:Name="HighlightBackground" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" />
                    </ContentPresenter>
                    <!--<FontIcon x:Name="DropDownGlyph" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E5;" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,10,10,10" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />-->
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                        <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeHighBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,-1,0,-1">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" MinWidth="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownContentMinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" VerticalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                <ItemsPresenter Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownContentMargin}" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It's just remove the `FontIcon` inside this control and make the `TextBlock`'s ColumnSpan = 2, and change it's foreground to `SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush`. If you want to modify it by your self, you can open the Document OutLine, find this ComboBox, right click on it, then choose  Edit Template then Edit a Copy, so you will get the default template of `ComboBox`:

[image]

Comment: I will try that, thank you. But how they used the ComboBox with the clickable TexTButton?

Comment: @andy, by clickable TextButton, you mean the item of the ComboBox?

Comment: I have added another Image for clarity and marked the clickable TextBlock.

Comment: @andy, You can modify the Template of the `Combobox`, change it's style like a `TextBlock`. But if you open your mobile emulator, you can find that the that this control looks different on mobile and PC, and the foreground is changed along with the system's theme. I updated the modified template in my answer, you can copy it to your page's resource and use it for the `ComboBox`.

Comment: I have tested it and it seems not to be a combobox in the alarms app. Only the snooze time, which has also only a text, seems to be a combobox.

Comment: @andy, what I've done is follow your wanted control of this app on the mobile, it's just a little different of style problem between pc and mobile, please try my code again.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, i was a little busy. Now i have done it, like you described and it seems now perfect for me. Thank you very much!