# How to have multiple selection of items on combobox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Hey I wanted to know how can I select multiple items from the combobox in XAML? 
Note: I'm using Data Binding.

Like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CheckBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.checkbox.aspx) as the Items of `ComboBox`.

And when the `CheckBox` is checked, it is important to modify the [PlaceholderText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.placeholdertext.aspx) of `ComboBox`, by default it will show the selected Item, but we can modify it to show all the items which is checked.

For example here: [How to make a List of CheckBoxes like in the Alarm & Clock App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674711/how-to-make-a-list-of-checkboxes-like-in-the-alarm-clock-app/36689482#36689482).

Comment: Thank You for your reply Grace , but i already have Data Binding in the ItemSource of my Combobox , but when i put the Data Template , it just shows Checkbox , but the Item text/label is not there...

Comment: @NicoTing, the `Content` property of `CheckBox` should be the text/lable. Please show your code.

Comment: `<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Header="Category" Margin="10,5,10,0"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>`

Comment: you see my itemsource is Categories , but how can i make the Checkbox contains those items too?

Comment: @NicoTing, as I said, the `Content` property of `CheckBox` should be the item text or lable, please follow my another case in my answer.

Comment: im sorry , im just a junior dev, still studying , yes i see your example , so do i need to set a new property and get the Categories content and assign that to my CheckBox?

Comment: @NicoTing, I don't know what you mean by new property, just from the image you posted in the question, you can just use the content property of checkbox to show the text, there is no need to create a property for checkbox(am I thinking too much?). Or if your new property just means the property in the data model for data binding, then yes, you are right, it is needed.